# m4a not playing ios push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an m4a sound that I have downloaded to my app sandbox which is not playing.  I know the application sees it because when I send an APNS with sound "siren.m4a" it makes no noise, but if I change the notification sound to sirens.m4a it makes the default noise.  What's more, when I play the sound in iTunes, it works just fine!  By the way settings shows that I have the sound notification permission.  The file is 20s long.

I saw somebody else had a similar question, but this is different because it's obvious that ios actually sees the file.  It is in /Library/Sounds

Comment: Try the same thing with a 2 second long clip and see if it fixes the problem. Not sure if they require a certain length but it's good to try

Comment: What do you mean by "It is in /Library/Sounds"?

Comment: Apple says to put sounds in the Library/Sounds folder of the application sandbox